# How to pass data in configmap as secret Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I am deploying a gitlab runner in K8s cluster and I need to pass data [enviroment,token,url] in configmap as secret.below are the deployment and configmap manifest files.

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner
  namespace: gitlab-runner
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: gitlab-runner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: gitlab-runner
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      serviceAccountName: default
      containers:
        - args:
          - run
          image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: gitlab-runner
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "100m"
            limits:
              cpu: "100m"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
              readOnly: true
              subPath: config.toml
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: gitlab-runner-config
      restartPolicy: Always
```

config.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner-config
  namespace: gitlab-runner
data:
  config.toml: |-
    concurrent = 4
    [[runners]]
      name = "Kubernetes Runner"
      url = "gitlab url"
      token = "secrettoken"
      executor = "kubernetes"
      environment = 
      ["TEST_VAR=THIS_IS_TEST_VAR_PRINTING", "SECOUND_TEST_VAR=This_is_2nd_test_var"]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "gitlab-runner"
        privileged = true
        poll_timeout = 600
        cpu_request = "1"
        service_cpu_request = "200m"
         [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
            name = "docker"
            mount_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
            host_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
```

In the above configmap yaml I need to pass Enviroment ,token and url as kubernetes secret.

Comment: configmap are not secret, you can tried to define secret in k8s and using k8s.@Kevin Thomas

Comment: Is there any approach which you can suggest for this situation?